# How do I convert runtime.Object to a specific type?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm writing a custom controller with Kubebuilder framework, in one method, I got an object of type [`runtime.Object`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime#Object), I know I should be able to convert it to the specific type say `MyCustomResource`, but I cannot figure out how from the doc.

Comment: Do you already know the concrete type or do you need to do that too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be as easy as this:

```golang
func convertToMyCustomResource(obj runtime.Object) *v1alpha1.MyCustomResource {
  myobj := obj.(*v1alpha1.MyCustomResource)
  return myobj
}
```

If this produces an error (e.g. Impossible type assertion), make sure `MyCustomResource` satisfies the [`runtime.Object`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime#Object) interface; i.e.

1. Run the controller-gen tool to generate the `DeepCopyObject` method

   ```
   go run vendor/sigs.k8s.io/controller-tools/cmd/controller-gen/main.go paths=./api/... object
   ```
2. Add the `"k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1".TypeMeta` field to the `MyCustomResource` struct, which implements the `GetObjectKind` method.

```golang
    import (
      metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    )

    type MyCustomResource struct {
      metav1.TypeMeta `json:",inline"`
      // ... other stuff
    }
```

Comment: where is v1alpha1?  Where are things like Pods and StatefulSets located?  I can't figure out what to import... is it in the apimachinary repository (searching struct Pod) turns up nothing.

Comment: answer mentions correctly that type assertion panics(!) can happen. You can handle those accordingly by checking the second returned parameter:

myobj, ok := obj.(*v1alpha1.MyCustomResource)... if !ok { // handle error }